# Joomla 2.5 run one plugin before another

Tags: php, plugins, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla installation with these plugins installed:

DirectPHP which is a content plugin

Plugin Include Component which is a system plugin

I am running into the following error:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /nfs/c06/h06/mnt/157252/domains/bigideaadv.com/html/wright_specialty2_OLD/plugins/content/DirectPHP/DirectPHP.php(56) : eval()'d code on line 11
```

I believe my issue is that the include component plugin is rendering before the directPHP plugin. Is there a way to order how these fire off?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ordering for plugins on the admin side under Extensions->Plugin Manager. However, this error seems more of an issue with the coding in the plugin than the order they are running. I would try disabling each of the two plugins from the same plugin manager and seeing when you get the error.

Comment: David is right, the error is in the PHP you added to your content.